# MySQL / PHP query performance?

Tags: mysql, performance

Im in a dilema on which one of these methods are most efficient.

Suppose you have a query joining multiple tables and querying thousand of records. Than, you gotta get the total to paginate throughout all these results.

Is it faster to?

1) Do a complete select (suppose you have to select 50's columns), count the rows and than run another query with limits? (Will the MySQL cache help this case already selecting all the columns you need on the first query used to count?)

2) First do the query using COUNT function and than do the query to select the results you need.

3) Instead of using MySQL COUNT function, do the query selecting the ID's for example and use the PHP function mysql_num_rows?

- I think the number 2 is the best option, using MySQL built in COUNT function, but I know MySQL uses cache, so, selecting all the results on first query gonna be faster?

Thanks,

Comment: With regard to the query cache: It won't help you. The MySQL query cache is extremely simple-minded; all it does is return the exact same result set if you make the exact same query. Changing anything about the query, even if it's just the columns requested or the LIMIT, will make it run the whole thing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Found_Rows()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

> A `SELECT` statement may include a `LIMIT` clause to restrict the number
>   of rows the server returns to the client. In some cases, it is
>   desirable to know how many rows the statement would have returned
>   without the LIMIT, but without running the statement again. To obtain
>   this row count, include a `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` option in the `SELECT`
>   statement, and then invoke `FOUND_ROWS()` afterward:
>   `mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;`
>   `mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`
>   The second SELECT returns a number indicating how many rows the first SELECT`
>   would have returned had it been written without the LIMIT clause.

Comment: Note that adding SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS can slow down some queries significantly (as it may force the server to run a query to completion rather than just returning the first matching rows).

Comment: ^ Agree (but so would retrieving a count() and then executing the actual (limit'ed) query). Also not that this does not improve compatibility with other RDBMS'es since this is MySQL specific. On the performance: [here](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/) is an article exploring the performance hit.

Comment: This seems a good alternative. Thanks. Do you know if it will be faster than the solutions I presented?

Comment: @Henrique [I linked to an article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11532104/mysql-php-query-performance/11532160#comment15245880_11532160) explaining the performance differences (also make sure you read the comments there!). Having said that: there **IS NO** one-solution-fits-all answer here. There is only one correct semi-answer: measure and thou shall know. Each situation is unique and so is each possible solution. That's why we invented [profiling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is number 2, but the truth is that it will depend entirely on data size, tables, indexing, MySql version etc.

The only way of finding the answer to this is to try each one and measure how long they take. But like I say, my hunch would be number 2.